# Add an offset to current time

Tags: sql-server

I get an time difference value of 5.5 which should subtract 5 hours and 30 minutes from current date time .

```
select Dateadd(HH, -5.5,GETUTCDATE()),GETUTCDATE()
```

In output it only subtracts 5 hours .
I always get an value in form of this offset 5.5 or 13.5 likewise depending on the timezone..

Is this possible ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I always get an value in form of this offset 5.5 or 13.5 likewise depending on the timezone..

Then you can multiply the value by 60 and use `minute` datepart

```
select Dateadd(MINUTE, -5.5 * 60,GETUTCDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

time arithmetic always works in whole units - use -330 minutes instead

```
select Dateadd(MINUTE, -330,GETUTCDATE()),GETUTCDATE()
```

the input to the function is intended to be an integer (whole number) - you may be finding that -5.5 is truncating off the decimal part

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done.  First, you need to convert your decimal offset into minutes.  Then you can use [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186819.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as before.

```
DECLARE @Offset DECIMAL(18, 2)  = 5.5;  
DECLARE @Mins   INT             = 60 * @Offset;

-- Offsetting by decimal time values.
SELECT
    DATEADD(MINUTE, @Mins, GETDATE())
;
```